# How do I make the elements align into the same row instead of stacking up to 3 separate rows?

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js

(I'm new to web dev)
How do I make the elements align into the same row instead of stacking up to 3 separate rows? I'm trying to make a header bar of sorts that looks similar to the header bar in the Naive UI Documentation Website. I'm using Vue.js 3 with composition API and TypeScript and using the Naive UI Component Library and Tailwind CSS.

TopViewGuide.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {RouterLink, RouterView, useRouter} from 'vue-router'
import {
  NAvatar, NButton, NConfigProvider, NDialogProvider, NDropdown,
  NGradientText,
  NLayout, NLayoutHeader, NLoadingBarProvider, NMenu, NMessageProvider, NSpace
} from 'naive-ui'
import type { DropdownOption } from 'naive-ui'
import TopViewGuide from "@/views/Guides/TopViewGuide.vue";
const $router = useRouter();
import {h, ref} from 'vue'
import type {Component} from "vue";
import { NIcon } from 'naive-ui'
import type { MenuOption } from 'naive-ui'

function renderIcon (icon: Component) {
  return () => h(NIcon, null, { default: () => h(icon) })
}

const menuOptions: MenuOption[] = [
  {
    label: 'Home',
    key: 'home'
  },
  {
    label: 'Tools',
    key: 'tools'
  },
  {
    label: 'Schedules',
    key: 'schedules'
  },
  {
    label: 'Tasks',
    key: 'tasks'
  }
]

const activeKey = ref(), isLoggedIn = false;
const dropdownOptions: DropdownOption[] = [
  { label: "Account", key: "auth.principal" },
  { label: "Sign out", key: "auth.sign-out" },
];
function dropdownHandler(key: string) {
  $router.push({ name: key });
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-8 w-full">
    <div class="flex items-center cursor-pointer">
      <img src="@/assets/images/TaskJournal%20Icon.svg" width="40" height="40" />
      <NGradientText>TaskJournal</NGradientText>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow">
      <NMenu v-model:value="activeKey" mode="horizontal" :options="menuOptions"/>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="flex gap-3">
      <NButton type="primary">Get Started</NButton>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="flex gap-3">
      <NDropdown placement="bottom-end" show-arrow :options="dropdownOptions" @select="dropdownHandler">
        <NAvatar/>
      </NDropdown>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

LandingPage.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {RouterLink, RouterView, useRouter} from 'vue-router'
import {
  NAvatar, NButton, NConfigProvider, NDialogProvider, NDropdown,
  NGradientText,
  NLayout, NLayoutHeader, NLoadingBarProvider, NMenu, NMessageProvider, NSpace
} from 'naive-ui'
import type { DropdownOption } from 'naive-ui'
import TopViewGuide from "@/views/Guides/TopViewGuide.vue";
const $router = useRouter();
import {h, ref} from 'vue'
import type {Component} from "vue";
import { NIcon } from 'naive-ui'
import type { MenuOption } from 'naive-ui'
</script>

<template>
  <NDialogProvider>
    <NConfigProvider>
      <NMessageProvider>
        <NLoadingBarProvider>
          <NLayoutHeader bordered class="h-16 flex">
            <TopViewGuide/>
          </NLayoutHeader>
          <div class="w-full relative">
            <NLayout>
              <NGradientText>
                sadsada
              </NGradientText>
            </NLayout>
          </div>
        </NLoadingBarProvider>
      </NMessageProvider>
    </NConfigProvider>
  </NDialogProvider>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My App.vue only has a `<RouterView>` component under `<template>`.

I tried adding flex containers to each element but still didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgpNR.png)
I'm just extremely confused at this point.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-8 w-full">
    <div class="items-center cursor-pointer">
      <img src="@/assets/images/TaskJournal%20Icon.svg" width="40" height="40" />
      <NGradientText>TaskJournal</NGradientText>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <NMenu v-model:value="activeKey" mode="horizontal" :options="menuOptions"/>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="gap-3">
      <NButton type="primary">Get Started</NButton>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="gap-3">
      <NDropdown placement="bottom-end" show-arrow :options="dropdownOptions" @select="dropdownHandler">
        <NAvatar/>
      </NDropdown>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

a flex tag can has divs (or display: block tags) with one row.

see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Float" element.
The CSS float property is used for positioning and formatting content and allow elements float next to each other instead of on top of each other.

```
.mycontainer div {
   float:left;
}
```